# Differentiating a trig fraction. Check.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to differentiate this function:

$$y = \frac{\sin x}{1 + \tan x}$$

Is this right?

$$y' = \frac{(1+\tan x)\cos x - \sin x*\sec^2x}{(1 + \tan x)^2}$$

$$= \frac{\cos x + \sin x - \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}}{(1+\tan x)^2}$$

Am I doing something wrong? I feel like I can simplify the $1+\tan x$ but I'm a bit unsure how...

Comment: Use WA to verify: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+sin(x)%2F(1+%2B+tan(x))

Comment: Try writing \sin x instead of sin x, \cos x instead of cos x, \tan x instead of tan x and \tan x instead of tan t for your $\LaTeX$ commands.

Comment: I could get to $\frac {\cos^3 x + \cos x(\sin^2 x) - \sin x}{\sin {2x}+1}$. Not sure if that is what you wanted but if so, notify me and I will give an answer with the simplification.

Comment: that looks right! How do I get there?

Comment: @Jwan622 sorry I disconnected. I think Mehrdad Zandigohar answered that continued on what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. You can continue simplification.

First of all, you can conclude that:
$(1+\tan x)^2=(1+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x})^2=(\frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\cos x})^2=\frac{1+2\sin x \cos x}{\cos^2x}$

Then the simple form will be like below:
$y'= \frac{\cos x + \sin x - \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}}{(1+\tan x)^2}=
\frac{(\cos^2x)(\cos x + \sin x - \frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x})}{(\cos^2x)(1+\tan x)^2}=\frac{\cos^3x+\sin x\cos^2x-\sin x}{1+2\sin x\cos x}$
$=\frac{\cos^3x-\sin x(1-\cos^2x)}{1+2\sin x \cos x}=\frac{\cos^3x-\sin^3x}{1+2\sin x\cos x}=\frac{\cos^3x-\sin^3x}{\sin 2x +1}$

Comment: Why does 1+2sinxcosx = 1+sin2x

Comment: @Jwan622 $\sin {2x} = 2\sin x \cos x$ is a well known trigonometric identity. Do you need a proof for it? You could prove it yourself using $\sin {(A+B)}=\sin A \cos B+\cos A \sin B$.

Comment: Oh I see, but sin(a+a) = sinacosa + cosasina = 2sinacosa

Comment: @Jwan622 $\sin (2a)=\sin (a+a)$ if you are missing that

Comment: upvote me please!

Answer (score 1):

it is by the quotient rule
$$y'=\frac{\cos(x)(1+\tan(x))-\sin(x)(1+\tan^2(x))}{(1+\tan(x))^2}$$
note that $$(\tan(x))'=1+\tan^2(x)$$

Comment: I don't get the last line

Comment: Isn't the derivative of $tanx = sec^2x$

Comment: ok it is $$\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1+\tan^2(x)$$

Comment: a little trick from me for you!

Comment: @Jwan622, $\sec^2x = 1 + \tan^2x$.  Recall the Pythagorean trig identities.